# VBA Column copy move

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Nameitem()
Dim Baza As Range
Dim Lista As Range
For Each Lista In Range("C12:C32")
        For Each Baza In Range("[Back.xlsx]New_Games!$B$2:$B$10000")
            If Baza.Value = Lista.Value Then
        'copy E Column from Back(baza) to D in Lista
        else
        'no set value
        End if
    Next 
Next
End Sub
```

i just start write macro in excel and i need to help to write some function to copy EX column form 1 excel to DY column in another excel

Comment: A good way of learning the syntax needed is to record yourself performing the action with the Record Macro function - you can then take all the relevant bits and make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E:X").Copy _    
             Application.Workbooks("book2").Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D:Y")
```

You may substitute Application.Workbooks("...").Worksheets("...") with sheet codename when refering sheets in the same workbook as code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Workbook object to open another workbook.

```
Dim wbBaza As Workbook
Set wbBaza = Workbooks.Open("Back.xlsx")
```

Then you can access data in the other workbook by;

```
wbBaza.Sheets("New_Games").Range()
```

Loop it like in your code;

```
For Each Baza in wbBaza.Sheets("New_Games").Range("B2:B10000")
```

I dont understand what you mean by EX and DY column, but if its data in same rows as the values you comparing, just use ranges to cover also that column...
example:

```
For Each Baza in wbBaza.Sheets("New_Games").Range("B2:F10000")
```

Then if the destination column is F, you can.. for example use .Cells() to copy from;

```
Lista.Cells(1,1) = Baza.Cells(1,5)
```

This because Baza range is from B to F, so B,C,D,E,F=5

You ofcourse need to open the range for where to copy too... as in your code you only have that single column Range("C12:C32")

Edit; Oh right you need to copy from E:X to D:Y, still I would just make a loop trough .Cells in that case...

Wouldnt the awful version be like;

```
For Each Lista In Range("A12:X32")
    For Each Baza In wbBaza.Sheets("New_Games").Rows
        If Lista.Cells(1, 3) = Baza.Cells(1, 2) Then
            For iLoop = 5 To 25 ' E=5 to X=25
                Lista.Cells(1, iLoop - 1) = Baza.Cells(1, iLoop)
            Next
        End If
        If Baza.Row = 10000 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```